# entry.url forcing https

Tags: url, htaccess, link

{{ entry.url }} is generating a https:// link. I don't have SSL on this site, so the page errors out.

Settings > General > Site Url is "http://..."

My .htaccess is below (though I've read the redirect doesn't work on shared hosting).

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
    RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Aside from "Get an SSL certificate," any suggestions on a fix?

Comment: Are you setting siteUrl dynamically in public index.php or config/general.php?  Can you share them?  Do you have any plugins installed that interfere with siteUrl or link creation?

Comment: In config/general.php siteUrl is null... I have two plugins: contactform and simplemap. I don't think either of those would interfere.

Comment: I got the link to work, but it seems like a dumb workaround. For some reason, `http://example.com` redirects to `https://example.com` when I use {{ entry.Url }}, but when I use `http://www`. the redirect doesn't occur. I changed my Site Url to www. and created a redirect to www. in the .htaccess file.

Comment: I think the problem may be with HSTS, but I don't know enough about it to know if I'm right or not... also, it was only redirecting like this on mobile. Super weird.

Comment: HSTS is a Chrome only thing and you have to specifically register that domain with Google saying you want to opp-in to HSTS.  Is that something you did?

Comment: Then it's not that... I'm having the redirect problems on Safari iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I got the link to work, but it seems like a dumb workaround. For some reason, `http://example.com` redirects to `https://example.com` when I use {{ entry.Url }}, but when I use `http://www.` the redirect doesn't occur. I changed my Site Url to `www.` and created a redirect to `www.` in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and add the following condition to the .htaccess which should redirect everything to http, perhaps it'll work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```